# ARM modes when context switching a user process running on guest

Tags: arm, virtualization, hypervisor

It is my understanding (from [this article](https://lwn.net/Articles/557132/)) that on ARM, the hypervisor/VMM runs in HYP mode, the guest OS runs in SVC mode, and user processes on the guest run in USR mode.

When there is a context switch in the guest OS, say switching from one user process to another, does this trap all the way up to the VMM in HYP mode? And if so, what happens at each stage of the process, going from USR to to SVC to HYP modes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: depends on the hypervisor, architecture permits both approaches.

A context switch on ARM would be switching the Page Table and invalidating the TLB.

To switch Page Table, you need to modify the register TTBR0 (user-space part) or TTBR1 (kernel-space. normally for Linux it never changes but some exotic OS might be different) which are accessed via the "co-processor" instructions.

To set TTBR0 you use the instruction "MRC" with CRn = 2.

Such coprocessor accesses can be trapped by a HYP, but not necessarily. It depends on whether you request them to be trapped or not. This is set in the "Hypervisor System Trap Register" (HSTR_EL2 on aarch64).

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0488d/CIHJFIHA.html

TLB invalidation instructions and cache maintenance operations are also implemented as coprocessor access instructions on ARMv7 (technically also on ARMv8 but the Architecture Reference Manual suggests to use human-readable mnemonics instead). For example, "TLBIALL" is coprocessor CRn8 so you need to set bit T8 in HSTR_EL2.

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0438i/CIHECHCD.html